# Deep cloning in C# taking longer to execute on each call

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, cloning

I am trying to deep clone a list of 100 multi-property objects, I am using the code below to perform the deep clone. The list creation and the list cloning happen in a loop so each time around the loop the list changes its contents but remains fixed at 100 objects.

The problem is each time around the loop, cloning the list takes what seems to be exponentially longer than the last time it executed.

```
public static Main ()
{

List<Chromosome<Gene>> population = Population.randomHalfAndHalf(rand, data, 100, opset);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfGenerations; i++)
        {
                   offSpring = epoch.runEpoch(rand, population, SelectionMethod.Tournament, opset);
                    clone = DeepClone<List<Chromosome<Gene>>>(population);
                    clone.AddRange(offSpring);
                    population = fixPopulation(rand, clone, SelectionMethod.Tournament, 100);
        }

//....REST OF CODE....

}


public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
    {
        object result = null;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;

            result = (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
            ms.Close();
        }
        return (T)result;
    }
```

Some of you may be thinking why am I even cloning the object if I can write over the original population. This is a valid point and one that I have explored but what happens when I do that is that loop executes perfectly for about 8 iterations the first time I run it, then it idles and does nothing so I stop it. The the next time I execute it it goes to 9 iterations and stops, ideals, does nothing etc etc each time around the loop. If any one has any ideas as to why this is happening also please share as I really dont get why that is happening.

But my main problem is that the time to clone the object takes notablely longer each time around the above loop first by a few seconds then eventually up to 5 mins etc.

Any body have any ideas as to why this is happening?

**EDIT** I have profiled the application while it was running the majority of the work over 90% is being done by BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream) and here is fix population its doing nothing overly complex that would contribute to this problem.

```
private static List<Chromosome<Gene>> fixPopulation(Random rand, List<Chromosome<Gene>> oldPopulation, SelectionMethod selectionMethod, int populationSize)
    {
        if (selectionMethod == SelectionMethod.Tournament)
        {
            oldPopulation.Sort();
        }
        else
        {
            //NSGAII sorting method
        }

        oldPopulation.RemoveRange(populationSize, (oldPopulation.Count - populationSize));

        for (int i = 0, n = populationSize / 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            int c1 = rand.Next(populationSize);
            int c2 = rand.Next(populationSize);

            // swap two chromosomes
            Chromosome<Gene> temp = oldPopulation[c1];
            oldPopulation[c1] = oldPopulation[c2];
            oldPopulation[c2] = temp;
        }

        return oldPopulation;
    }
```

Comment: What does the `Gene` object look like? How is the offspring created in `runEpoch`? Does the `Gene` happen to hold a reference to a parent `Gene`? If so, while the list contains only 100 items, the total graph will grow for each iteration...

Comment: do you have a debugger? perhaps write a unit test?

Comment: @Fredrik the overall object Chromosome<Gene> is quite complex. The Chromosome has a property called genotype which can be set to a GeneNode where a GeneNode is a binary tree of Genes.    @Mitch & @sehe I am using visual studio 2010 show have access to both what woulf you recommend ??

Comment: Can you post fixPopulation? Binary tree? By any chance your binary tree or data associated with it, is not more and more complex with each iteration?

Comment: @macias posted fix population it doesnt really do much other than reduce the population size back down to its intended size and randomise it again. Binary tree is a looks of different classes so impractical to put up here

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary serialization to create a fast clone of your objects:

look at this :

```
public Entity Copy()
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            bFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            IEntityForm entity= (IEntityForm)bFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            return entity;
        }
```

really easy and working!

Comment: I am doing this the only difference being that you are specifying the memoryStream.Seek explicitly, even changing my code to reflect yours the problem remains.

Comment: did you checked for infinite loop or stack overflow ?

Comment: yep mitigated any stackoverflows it does finish in the end it just takes absolutely ages to do so.